# OpenSSL CA keyUsage extension

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I want to set up a chain of certificates, with a self signed 'root' CA at the top that signs sub CAs, which can then sign client and server certificates. When setting up `openssl.cnf`, I noticed a `keyUsage` parameter, which apparently needs to be set to whatever the key is supposed to be used for. While the parameter values are documented, I can't find any information about which ones to use in certain circumstances.

What do the `keyUsage` values mean, and what should I use in the following situations?

- Self signed root CA
- Intermediate CA (that can sign other CAs)
- Intermediate CA (that cannot sign other CAs)
- Non-CA certificates

Also, do other extensions need to be specified with certain values, such as `nsCertType`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Any CA certificate, no matter if it's a root or an intermediate, must have the `keyCertSign` extension. If you want to sign a revocation list (CRL) with the CA certificate as well (you usually do want that), than you have to add `cRLSign` as well. Any other keyUsages can and should be avoided for CA certificates.

The list of values accepted by openssl is [documented here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html).

For end-entity certificates you can use any of the other keyUsages as documented by openssl, just make sure you do not include the CA-extensions mentioned above. From a security perspective, you should not use more keyUsages then neccesary (especially it is advised to use seperate certificates for signing and encryption), but that is not a strict requirement.

Note that apart from the classic keyUsages, there is also the `extendedKeyUsage` (EKU) extension, which is not limited to predefined values in the RFC but can theoretically hold any OID you like. Known values are for instance for certificates to sign timestamps or OCSP responses.

You don't need to use `nsCertType`. Those, along with all the other ns* extensions, where defined by Netscape ages ago and should not be used anymore. You probably won't find any software around still using them.

A for other extensions, the only thing that is absoluetely required is the `basicConstraints` extension which has a boolean `CA` flag which you must set accordingly. The authorityKeyIdentifier and subjectkeyIdentifier extensions are also highly recommended.

Comment: OpenVPN has the `ns-cert-type` option, set by default in Arch's example `client.conf`, which looks for `nsCertType`. Interesting how it is still used in some places.

Comment: Also, how would keyUsage apply for non-CA certs? I edited the question to include it.

Comment: @Xenopathic `nc-cert-type` really should no longer be used in OpenVPN, as the "ns" stands for NetScape, as in the now defunct NetScape Browser.   The option `remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"` should be used, provided the server cert was generated with EKU `serverAuth` and the client cert(s) generated with EKU `clientAuth`.  One can also specify `remote-cert-ku <hex value>`, where <hex value> is the hex value of KUs assigned.

Comment: The openssl documentation does have a list of values, but unfortunately absolutely zero explanation of what they mean (and is therefore effectively useless).

Answer (score 127):

<sup>***Custom [`openssl.cnf`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf) ([info](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL)) and [how to use](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800), with commands required beginning on Line 430***</sup>

## Certificate Authorities & Intermediate CAs

---

#### Self-signed CA

- ***keyUsage:*** `cRLSign`, `digitalSignature`, `keyCertSign` 
   <sup>***(Should not contain any other KUs and no EKUs)***</sup>
- ***V3 Profile:***

  ```ini
  [ v3_ca ]
  basicConstraints        = critical, CA:TRUE
  subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
  authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
  keyUsage                = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
  subjectAltName          = @alt_ca
  ```

#### Intermediate CA

- ***keyUsage:*** `cRLSign`, `digitalSignature`, `keyCertSign` 
   <sup>***(Should not contain any other KUs and no EKUs)***</sup>
- ***V3 Profile:***

  ```ini
  [ v3_ica ]
  basicConstraints        = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
  subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
  authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
  keyUsage                = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
  subjectAltName          = @alt_ica
  ```

  - *Where **`pathlen:`** is equal to the number of CAs/ICAs it can sign* 
     <sup>*(if pathlen is not specified/number set, it can sign an infinite/specified number of CAs/ICAs)*</sup>

---

---

## Non-CA Certificates

---

#### VPN/Web Server

- ***keyUsage:*** `nonRepudiation`, `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment`, `keyAgreement`
- ***V3 Profile:***

  ```ini
  [ v3_vpn_server ]
  basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
  subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
  authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
  keyUsage                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement 
  extendedKeyUsage        = critical, serverAuth
  subjectAltName          = @alt_vpn_server
  ```

#### VPN Client

- ***keyUsage:*** `nonRepudiation`, `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment`
- ***V3 Profile:***

  ```ini
  [ v3_vpn_client ]
  basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
  subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
  authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
  keyUsage                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
  extendedKeyUsage        = critical, clientAuth
  subjectAltName          = @alt_vpn_client
  ```

---

---

## `keyUsage`

---

## CA ONLY

**`keyCertSign`**

- Subject public key is used to verify signatures on certificates
- *This extension must only be used for CA certificates*

**`cRLSign`**

- Subject public key is to verify signatures on revocation information, such as a CRL
- *This extension must only be used for CA certificates*

---

**`digitalSignature`**

- Certificate may be used to apply a digital signature

  - Digital signatures are often used for entity authentication & data origin authentication with integrity

**`nonRepudiation`**

- Certificate may be used to sign data as above but the certificate public key may be used to provide non-repudiation services

  - This prevents the signing entity from falsely denying some action

**`keyEncipherment`**

- Certificate may be used to encrypt a symmetric key which is then transferred to the target

  - Target decrypts key, subsequently using it to encrypt & decrypt data between the entities

**`dataEncipherment`**

- Certificate may be used to encrypt & decrypt actual application data

**`keyAgreement`**

- Certificate enables use of a key agreement protocol to establish a symmetric key with a target
- Symmetric key may then be used to encrypt & decrypt data sent between the entities

**`encipherOnly`**

- Public key used only for enciphering data while performing key agreement

  - ***Req. KU:** `keyAgreement`*

**`decipherOnly`**

- Public key used only for deciphering data while performing key agreement

  - ***Req. KU:** `keyAgreement`*

---

#### RFC 5280 [[4.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3)]

**`id-ce-keyUsage OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-ce 15 }`**

- *Bitstring is hexadecimal*

  ```php
  keyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
    digitalSignature    (0),
    nonRepudiation      (1),
    keyEncipherment     (2),
    dataEncipherment    (3),
    keyAgreement        (4),
    keyCertSign         (5),
    cRLSign             (6),
    encipherOnly        (7),
    decipherOnly        (8)
  }
  ```

---

---

## `extendedKeyUsage`

---

<sup>***CAs/ICAs should not have any EKUs specified***</sup>

**`serverAuth`**

- All VPN/Web servers should be signed with this EKU present 
   <sup>*(this supersedes `nscertype` options, as `ns` in `nscertype` stands for NetScape [browser])*</sup>

  - SSL/TLS VPN/Web Server authentication EKU, distinguishing a server which clients can authenticate against
  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement`*

**`clientAuth`**

- All VPN clients must be signed with this EKU present

  - SSL/TLS Web/VPN Client authentication EKU distinguishing a client as a client only
  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature` and/or `keyAgreement`*

**`codeSigning`**

- Code Signing

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `nonRepudiation`, and/or `keyEncipherment`* or *`keyAgreement`*

**`emailProtection`**

- Email Protection via S/MIME, allows you to send and receive encrypted emails

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement`*

**`timeStamping`**

- Trusted Timestamping

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `nonRepudiation`*

**`OCSPSigning`**

- OCSP Signing

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `nonRepudiation`*

**`msCodeInd`**

- Microsoft Individual Code Signing (authenticode)

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement`*

**`msCodeCom`**

- Microsoft Commerical Code Signing (authenticode)

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement`*

**`mcCTLSign`**

- Microsoft Trust List Signing

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `nonRepudiation`*

**`msEFS`**

- Microsoft Encrypted File System Signing

  - ***Req. KU:** `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement`*

---

## !!! SHOULD NOT BE UTILIZED !!!

*`ipsecEndSystem`*, *`ipsecTunnel`*, & *`ipsecUser`*

- Assigned in 1999, the semantics of these values were never clearly defined
- *RFC 4945:* The use of these three EKU values is obsolete and explicitly deprecated by this specification <sup>[*[5.1.3.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4945#section-5.1.3.12)*]</sup>

*`ipsecIKE`*

- IPSec Internet Key Exchange 
   <sup>*(I believe this is in the same boat as the three above)*</sup>
- *Research needs to be performed to determine if this EKU should also no longer be utilized* 
   <sup>*(`clientAuth` can be utilized in an IPSec VPN client cert)*</sup>

---

#### RFC 5280 [[4.2.1.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12)]

**`anyExtendedKeyUsage  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-ce-extKeyUsage 0 }`**

- **`id-kp  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-pkix 3 }`**

  - **`id-kp-serverAuth OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 1 }`**

    - TLS server authentication

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`*, *`keyEncipherment`* or *`keyAgreement`*
  - **`id-kp-clientAuth OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 2 }`**

    - TLS client authentication

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`* and/or *`keyAgreement`*
  - **`id-kp-codeSigning  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 3 }`**

    - Signing of downloadable executable code

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`*
  - **`id-kp-emailProtection  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 4 }`**

    - Email protection

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`*, *`nonRepudiation`*, and/or *`keyEncipherment`* or *`keyAgreement`*
  - **`id-kp-timeStamping OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 8 }`**

    - Binding the hash of an object to a time

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`* and/or *`nonRepudiation`*
  - **`id-kp-OCSPSigning  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 9 }`**

    - Signing OCSP responses

      - KU bits for: 
         *`digitalSignature`* and/or *`nonRepudiation`*

Comment: When you say "_SSL/TLS Web/VPN Client authentication EKU distinguishing a client as a client only_" means is not possible to have a just one certificate that works to both server and client?

Comment: It's possible to add both EKUs, however there shouldn't be any reason to do so, as I'm not aware of any server daemon that can act as both a client and a server at the same time, off the same config (or vice versa).

Comment: @JW0914 for example Bacula uses the same cert for both server and client connections - I had to create a certificate that had keyUsage set to ns server and ns client at the same time. It did not work without this.

Comment: @Edheldil Netscape [browser] EKUs should not be used and if Bacula is still using them, that instance likely needs updating - correct EKUs are `serverAuth` and `clientAuth`. Using the same cert for a server and client is a security risk and not advised, as doing so enables an MITM attack to occur. If you are using the most current Bacula version, you may want to email tech support and ask how that's secure, requesting a detailed explanation.