# Openssl asks for password and common name but I want to send them as parameter

Tags: certificate, openssl

I'm creating a certificate using this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -config localhost.conf
```

with this config:

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_keyfile    = localhost.key
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
x509_extensions    = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = localhost
commonName_max              = 64

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
basicConstraints = critical, CA:false
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature,keyEncipherment

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
```

But the command asks for a `Common name` and `password`, How can I send them as the parameter to `openssl`. I tried other solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: Why do you have the key usages of `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign` when you're asserting that you are _not_ a CA? Read [RFC 5280 Section 4.2.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3)

Comment: It's asking for a password because your command is malformed - the order of `openssl req` matters, so move `-nodes` to the end of the command. If this isn't a CA/ICA, your certificate is insecure _(it has no CoT [Chain of Trust] and has KUs only a CA/ICA should have)_. Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1248085/529800) answer for KUs and EKUs, [this](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800) answer for how to correctly create the certificate, and [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf) example `openssl.cnf` for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-subj` on the command line to pass the certificate's Subject.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -config localhost.conf -subj "/O=My Org/OU=My Dept/CN=My Service"
```

Comment: @JW0914 - maybe that is version dependent?  Mine, on OpenSSL 1.1.1 installed on Debian 11 didn't ask for a password, even with `-nodes` in the current position.  How odd...

Comment: That's because the `openssl.cnf` you're using has `encrypt_key = ` set to `no`, whereas by default, most have it set to `yes`. `-nodes` is required when creating server certs with `encrypt_key = yes`, else the server key will be encrypted, which is impractical/potentially detrimental.

Comment: @JW0914 - I've just double checked.  Using the OP's config file above, which hasn't got `encrypt_key` at all, I ran the command as is and I wasn't prompted for a password.  Also tried Fedora 35 and that doesn't prompt neither (same OpenSSL though).  However, if moving it to the end fixes it for the OP, then all's well.

Comment: `openssl.cnf` content posted in the OP isn't a complete `openssl.cnf`. If `-nodes` is in a command, its sole purpose is to create a key w/o encryption when `encrypt_key = yes` is in an `openssl.cnf`, so when a command includes it, by default we must assume it's included due to that _(please see the `openssl` man pages)_. `openssl req` combines cert/csr and key creation into a single command, however parameter order matters, as the first part of the command is for cert parameters, whereas key parameters need to be specified after `-newkey` _(specifying them out of order malforms the command)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ For a working example of this, please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800) answer

Comment: @JW0914 - there is no requirement to use all possible options in the `openssl.cnf` file, only the minimum required to do the task in hand.  Saying that, I added `encrypt_key = yes` to the OP's config file and ran it with the `-nodes` in the position shown and it didn't prompt for a password.  Just to confirm, I removed `-nodes` and it did prompt, suggesting that it is doing  something at that early position?

Comment: I stand corrected then - it seems to be the exception to the rule, as trying to process key parameters before `-newkey` usually creates a malformed command _(unless OpenSSL devs changed this - I'll test for tomorrow)_. For the `openssl.cnf`, I wasn't implying all options need to be used, just that it's missing some vital options, which is why I believed it to not be the complete config _(e.g. `default_md = sha512` (or 256),  `string_mask = utf8only`, entire `[ CA ]`/`[ CA_default ]` section is missing, etc.)_, coupled with `-nodes`, but no `encrypt_key`